# webpack-cli : Error: spawn Unknown system error -86 / Symfony

Tags: npm

I have just acquired a new mac with M1 chip and I wonder if the error is related to this, because on my old one I have no problem.

```
[webpack-cli] Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
    at Object.execFile (node:child_process:325:17)
    at Object.module.exports.fileCommandJson (/Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/node-notifier/lib/utils.js:88:13)
    at NotificationCenter.notifyRaw (/Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/notificationcenter.js:81:11)
    at WebpackNotifierPlugin.compilationDone (/Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/webpack-notifier/index.js:129:14)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:18:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at /Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:498:23
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/mlc/Sites/ImapImport/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:906:5) {
  errno: -86,
  code: 'Unknown system error -86',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

It occurs when the command is launched:

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
yarn encore dev
```

I have already tried deleting the node_modules file as well as the package-lock.json, and clearing the npm cache then re-running npm install but nothing worked.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I got my new M1 Pro as well and I had the same issue. The interesting thing is that the `npm run prod` created all files correctly.

First I checked if `xcode-select --install` is installed - it was.

Next I checked the installed git version `git --version` -> `git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)`, standard Apple git. I installed a fresh git via homebrew `brew install git` and restarted my Mac. After that the error was gone.

If this does not fix your error, maybe it is an weird npm package.

Comment: Doesn't work, I also tried to reinstall node everything but it doesn't work either, I'm disappointed..

Comment: Did you installed node via brew or via the Apple Silikon Pack in the node website?

Comment: To say, I tested with the version of the official site but also with that of homebrew, neither of them works.

Comment: If you tried out both version, you uninstalled the other before that? Can you try run 'npm run dev' with just one package? Please show your package.json.

Answer (score 4):

One other solution - instead of replacing a path in your node_modules - is installing rosetta.
This seems to be the best workaround mentioned in the [node-notifier repository](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/issues/361#issuecomment-968916810)

Simply run `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me:

Install terminal-notifier via brew

brew install terminal-notifier

Make note of the folder/directory that brew installed the app into (for me this was: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/terminal-notifier/2.0.0 )

Edit the nitificationscenter.js inside of your project

node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/notificationcenter.js

10th or so line down:

'../vendor/mac.noindex/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier'

Comment-out/Delete it and replace with the path to your new brew installed terminal-notifier.  For me that was:

'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/terminal-notifier/2.0.0/terminal-notifier'

You'll have to edit the notificationcenter.js for each of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thanks to @andreasm for pointing me in the right direction.
I explain myself after checking on xcode was installed with the command :

```
xcode-select -p
```

it was, so I did not carry more attention than that, today just out of curiosity by executing :

```
xcode-select --install
```

the error has disappeared, morality: Do not trust the first command.