# webpack-cli Error: spawn Unknown system error -86 on MacBook Air M2 with Node.js v14.16.0

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, webpack

I'm encountering a recurring issue on my newly set up MacBook Air M2 (running macOS Sonoma 14.3), where the `npm run dev` command fails across different Node.js projects. Regardless of the project, I receive the following error message:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:408:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:677:9)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:311:17)
    at Object.module.exports.fileCommandJson (/Users/kerem/www/returo-2024/node_modules/node-notifier/lib/utils.js:88:13)
    at NotificationCenter.notifyRaw (/Users/kerem/www/returo-2024/node_modules/node-notifier/notifiers/notificationcenter.js:81:11)
    at WebpackNotifierPlugin.compilationDone (/Users/kerem/www/returo-2024/node_modules/webpack-notifier/index.js:129:14)
    at _next1 (eval at create (/Users/kerem/www/returo-2024/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:39:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/kerem/www/returo-2024/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:63:1) {
  errno: -86,
  code: 'Unknown system error -86',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ watch: `mix watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kerem/.npm/_logs/2024-01-25T10_36_28_686Z-debug.log
➜  returo-2024 git:(master) ✗
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

- Reinstalling Node.js and NVM.
- Running in various projects (error occurs regardless of the project and node version).
- Checking global and local npm installations and dependencies.

Comment: I would suggest going through these threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987542/webpack-cli-error-spawn-unknown-system-error-86-symfony https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74463679/webpack-cli-error-spawn-unknown-system-error-86-symfony6-mac-m1